# Any SDK for xamarin-android for app to app voIP calling other than Twilio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mono, voip

Anyone can please suggest SDK for VoIP calls for **Xamarin**. I have been searching over the internet since a couple of weeks but I couldn't find anything reliable. I communicated with Twilio but they do not have Twilio Client for Xamarin yet.
I have also seen CometChat, PortSIP, Tropo but none of these is helpful for xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not find a Xamarin specific SDK you can still go with a native one and build a binding for it. See [Xamarin docs for binding a java library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) to get you started.

Comment: you mean i can use native android sdk (i.e native android based) and use that in my xamarin-android(with C#)? through this bindings? correct?

Comment: The type 'DisconnectedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0' 
i am having this error, can you please help in this regard? i tried to put custom binding in MetaDeta.xml like this
"<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.twilio.client']/class[@name='ConnectionListener']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">p0_2</attr>"
but i could not fix

Comment: Without looking at the whole binding, no. But maybe someone else can jump in. Therefor I would suggest to open a new question with the specific tags.